# How to alter characters at certain positions in a string

Tags: go

For string like "AA_BB_CC", I would like to turn it into "AaBbCc". I thought I could do it like:

```
func CapsToCamel() string {
  var buf bytes.Buffer
  s := "AA_BB_CC"
  toUpper := true
  for i :=0; i<len(s); i++ {
    if toUpper {
       buf.WriteString(strings.ToUpper(s[i])) // error: s[i] is of byte.
    ...
}
```

I stopped there, although I could treat each `s[i]` as an ASCII char, and then compare its value with `a` and `z`, but I think there should be a Go way to do it.

Comment: You need to convert it back to string: `string(s[i])`

Comment: @zerkms that works! But is this a Go way to do it (turn a string into a byte and play with each byte)?

Comment: Have a look here though: https://play.golang.org/p/m0iX49jlxNl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more cleaner working solution using only the `strings` package without having to rely on using `bytes.Buffer`.

```
func CapsToCamel(s string) string {
    newstr := ""
    str := []byte(strings.Join(strings.Split(s, "_"), ""))

    for i := 0; i < len(str); i += 2 {
        newstr += string(str[i])
        newstr += strings.ToLower(string(str[i]))
    }
    return newstr
}
```

A simple example is also available on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/1YIeTlr8a6D